# Apply HTML changes to 3rd party Website permanently in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css, web-development, developer-tools

I have to use a 3rd party website, that only runs fine in the Internet Explorer.

But I still need to edit the HTML of some of the pages by using the F12 Developer Tools. Otherwise it would be very uncomfortable to use them.

How can I apply this changes - or HTML changes in general - every time I visit this pages?
A local HTML file is not an option, because the page loads content from the server and the server will not allow access from external domains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something, that helps. I can enable the Accessibility feature of the Internet Exporer and point to a css file, that will be applied to every page I open.

Now I have to enable or disable this file, depending on the site I use at the moment. Not perfect, but quite good.

In IE11 it is found here:
`Internet Settings > Accessibility > Format document by using your own stylesheet`